# Invalid syntax in python program

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I wrote a program that gives a set of numbers for the european lottery. The lottery consists of 5 so-called numbers, which you have to choose from the numbers from 1 to 50, and 2 so-called stars, which you have to choose from the numbers from 1 to 11. It worked right, but I wanted it to take input from the user saying how many sets of numbers and stars the user wanted and printing all of them. However, I get an invalid syntax error. Here's the program:

```
import random

print "This program doesn't increase the chances of winning the lottery!"

numbers=range(1, 51)

stars=range(1,12)

sets=int(raw_input("Insert number of sets here")

for i in range(sets+1): 

        a=sorted(random.sample(numbers, 5))
        print "The numbers are", a
        b=sorted(random.sample(stars, 2))       
        print "The stars are", b

print "Good luck!"
```

The shell highlights the colon but I don't know why? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use an ide or linter to spot syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

When the Python interpreter raises a SyntaxError, it will indicate the line (and even location within the line) where it recognized a syntax error has occurred.

However, the *actual* syntax error often happens at some point prior to the location where Python *realized* there is a SyntaxError because code can be syntactically valid even if it is not what is intended.

In this case, you are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
sets=int(raw_input("Insert number of sets here")  # <-- Add `)` here to fix.
```

Note that [some editors](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors) have parenthesis and brace highlighting which can help you see where (and when) they are closed. Emacs and vim are two popular choices.

Comment: Thanks. I feel so dumb right now.